# Add gridlines to a output plot in Mathemaitca

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to add gridlines to a output density plot in Mathematica. The plot is generated by a long calculation in Mathematica and when I do the plot I forget to add the Mesh->True options. I don't want to do all the calculation and generate the plot again since it takes a long time. Is that possible to add the gridlines or mesh lines to plot ONLY using the output plot at hand?

For example, If I have a plot p. Is it possible to add the mesh lines ONLY manipulate p?

In a ordinary one dimensional plot, this will work

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}];

Insert[p1, GridLines -> Automatic, -1]
```

[image]

But when I try the density plot, it seems the gridlines is always under the plot, and can be seen only at the image margin area.

```
p2 = DensityPlot[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.2];
Insert[p2, GridLines -> Automatic, -1]
```

[image]

**Updata**

The Mesh option on the output plot will not work because Mesh is not a options of a Graphics:

```
Show[p2,Mesh->True]
```

will give a message "an unrecoginzed option name(Mesh) was encountered while rendering a Graphics"
Thanks.

Comment: The equivalent of `GridLines` for `DensityPlot` is `Mesh`, thought I can't help on your problem.

Comment: It seems like the lines created by `Mesh` are not added via the options, since `AbsoluteOptions[DensityPlot[1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> 10]]==AbsoluteOptions[DensityPlot[1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]]` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is a horrible hack but it does work (at least sometimes). The idea is to create a mesh in a density plot that is easy to compute but otherwise resembles your p2 and then to extract out the mesh.

```
Show[p2, Graphics[Cases[DensityPlot[0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
      Evaluate[Sequence @@ Append[Options[p2], Mesh -> True]]][[1]] //
     Normal, _Line, \[Infinity]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is via the `"GridLinesInFront"` method option for `Graphics`:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.2, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image]